# Blender crashes when inserting a keyframe via Python

Tags: python, materials, keyframes

I'm trying to programmatically vary the strength of an Emission surface and insert keyframes in Blender. I can vary the strength of an the emission, but when I try to insert a keyframe the software crashes. I don't have any new insight after reading the API Gotchas, so now I'm wondering if I'm ignorant of a fundamental or am having a system issue.

[Here's a link to the file](https://pasteall.org/blend/52f4960a1382487d84dfe9d71e74ae68), and here's the relevant code:

```
import bpy
import os

#clear the terminal window
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def emission_control():
    
    #initialize the starting key frame used in the loop
    start_key = 0
    
    #drop the initial keyframe
    matl = 'TestMatl'
    emiss = 'Emission'
    
    #these lines of code work--the emission strength change in the Object window 
    emiss_matl = bpy.data.materials[matl].node_tree.nodes[emiss].inputs[1]
    emiss_matl.default_value = 10
    
    #this line causes Blender to crash
    emiss_matl.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'default_value', frame = start_key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   emission_control()
```

System information:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Blender v2.82a

Comment: It's a bug in 2.82a.  2.82a is no longer supported; you need to update to at least 2.83LTS to get support.  However 2.83LTS will stop being supported in a couple of months; so better to upgrade to 2.93LTS at least

Comment: i'll upgrade and attempt again. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the software version solved the issue. The crashing was indeed due to a bug in v2.82a.